# My c# login server doesn't recognize my usernames and passwords

Tags: c#, database, passwords, text-files, windows-forms-designer

So, I'm trying to create my first login/register page and for the most part it works, besides the case in which I have to scan the username and password data form the text file. It always says that they are incorrect, even if I copy them form the text file. They are registered correctly but then I can't use them. Either the program doesn't read them properly or i have done something wrong when I added them. Can someone please help me?

```
private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(UsernameLogin.Text=="")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter your username and try again");
        UsernameLogin.Focus();
    }
    else
    if(PasswordLogin.Text=="")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter your password and try again");
        PasswordLogin.Focus();
    }
    else
    {
        string[] words = File.ReadAllText("data.txt").Split(' ');
        for (int j = 0; j < words.Length; j++) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(words[j]);
            Console.Read();
        }
        bool condition = false;
        for(int i=0; i<words.Length;i++)
        {
            if (UsernameLogin.Text == words[i] && PasswordLogin.Text == words[i+1])
            {
                condition = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Login succesful");
            }
           
        }
        if (condition == false)
            MessageBox.Show("Username or password invalid. Please try again.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have more than one line in that file? If yes there is a newline string after each line. Change _words[i].Trim()_ and _words[i+1].Trim()_ Side note. I suggest to read line by line with File.ReadLines in a loop and then split the single line in two words

Comment: I get that this is for learning purposes. _But_: If it's about UI design, maybe design something else. If it is specifically about Login/Register: try and do it right and _do not use anything close to clear-text passwords_.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I managed to solve the problem.